# Issue when installing CVX in MATLAB 2021a with cvx_setup on MacOS, cvx/sedumi/.travis.yml is missing

Tags: matlab, cvx

I've just downloaded CVX 2.2 on my MacOS (10.14.5), unzipped CVX, started MATLAB 2021a, changed the directory to the CVX unpacked folder and ran the cvx_setup file for the installation. Installation seems successful, but I get this warning message:

```
WARNING: The following files/directories are missing:
        /Users/myname/Downloads/cvx/sedumi/.travis.yml
    These omissions may prevent CVX from operating properly.
```

The file is concretely missing, may it be quarantined? I tried to check if it is and remove it from quarantine with the following terminal commands:

```
xattr /Users/myname/Downloads/cvx
com.apple.quarantine
sudo xattr -r -d com.apple.quarantine /Users/myname/Downloads/cvx
```

But same warning message occurs. Have you any suggestion? What if I continue without this file?